# Retropie - Cable-connected PS3 Controller crazy/ghost moves

Tags: retropie, emulation, gamepad

Greetings to the community!

I have set up my **raspberry pi 4** with **retropie**, connected it through an HDMI cable to my monitor and boot it ready to play. I connected a PS3 controller I own through a USB cable on it, pressed a random button as the retropie prompted on the screen to be recognized, so far so good.

Unfortunately after that, the controller starts to get "crazy" making random and ghost moves, of for example, I am pressing L2 and starts going left-right multiple times in the initial menu. **I tried to connect a second one PS3 Controller in case something was wrong** with the first one but in vain as the same situation remains.

Could this be anything "driver-related"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the last paragraph on https://retropie.org.uk/docs/PS3-Controller/ - does that sound like it may be the issue?

Comment: Hello Andyroo, thanks for your reply, well both of my controllers are genuine and perfecly functional with my PS3 I did not face any problem ever, concerning this `If analog input isn't strictly necessary to you, you can try to map one of the sticks as a d-pad and adjust its dead zone if you still have phantom menu navigation.`, Unfortunately I am not even able to navigate to the menu correcly to set up keys because of this crazy behaviour of the controller :/

Comment: There is a note here https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/14547/ps3-controllers/5 on Bluetooth you could try connecting the controller then powering on the Pi - total guess though as yours is USB!  One other thing to try is a third party driver for them documented at http://thomas-messmer.com/index.php/14-free-knowledge/howtos/67-retropie-controller-pairing-problems but other than that I'm out of ideas - sorry.